# Modulus and remainders - Javascript

Tags: javascript, modulus

Sorry for the two questions in such a short amount of time lol
Why do 1%15, 3%15, 5%15 have 0 remainder?
I may be rusty on math but I thought they should have remainders.

May be unnecessary but here is the code:

```
for (i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
    if (i % 15 === 0) {
        console.log("FizzBuzz");
    }
    else if (i % 3 === 0) {
        console.log("Fizz");
    }
    else if (i % 5 === 0) {
        console.log("Buzz");
    }
    else {
        console.log(i);
    }
}
```

and output:

```
**FizzBuzz** 
2
**FizzBuzz** 
4
**FizzBuzz**
Fizz 
7 
8 
Fizz 
Buzz 
11 
Fizz 
13 
14 
FizzBuzz 
16 
17 
Fizz 
19 
Buzz
```

Comment: Please have another go at formatting the code to make it readable. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, don't know why that happened, just edited as you typed probably lol

Answer (score 2):

The JavaScript expressions `1%15`, `3%15`, and `5%15` evaluate to 1, 3, and 5 respectively, as you surmised.

The question you asked seems unrelated to your code post, though, where you are using `15%i` and `i%3` and so on.

On the other hand, `15%1`, `15%3`, and `15%5` *do* all evaluate to zero.

Comment: shit.... sorry.  I copied the wrong code....
if  1%15, 3%15, and 5%15 don't evaluate to 0 then my code shouldn't have printed properly right?

Comment: Hard to say.  Someone edited your original question so that it should work.  Also, there are no asterisks in the code but there are in the output. From what I remember about the original code, saying `15%i` does produce FizzBuzz at 1, 3, and 5, which corresponds to the output in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are not asking 1%15, 3%15, 5%15... you are asking 15%1, 15%3, 15%5. :)

To clarify, this should get you the result you are after.

```
for(i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
   if(i%15 === 0) { 
      console.log("FizzBuzz"); 
   } else if(i%3 === 0) { 
      console.log("Fizz"); 
   } else if(i%5 === 0) { 
      console.log("Buzz"); 
   } else { 
      console.log(i); 
   }
}
```

Output:

```
1
2
Fizz
4
Buzz
Fizz
7
8
Fizz
Buzz
11
Fizz
13
14
FizzBuzz
16
17
Fizz
19
Buzz
```